# What is the purpose of %mdat (as compared to %udat) in Embperl?

Tags: perl, session-variables, embperl

I saw that session handling mentioned an `%mdat` as well as `%udat` hash. What is the difference and when and why would I use the `%mdat` hash?

Answer (score 3):

As noted in [Embperl POD](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aEmbperl#Session_handling),

> You can store any data in the `%mdat` hash and if any request comes to the same Embperl document, you will see the same values in that hash again.

Also, please note that the "you will see" wording in POD above is somewhat misleading, which may have contributed to your confusion.

The [main Embperl documentation](http://perl.apache.org/embperl/pod/doc/Embperl.-page-5-.htm#sect_16) provides a more precise answer that removes the confusion:

> The next time **any user** hits the same Embperl page, Embperl fill the `%mdat` hash from `Apache::Session` with the same values as you have stored within the last request to that page.

Please note the text I highlighted in bold - **any user**. Typical session data (as stored in `%udat`) is only stored and accessible **for a specific user**.

Therefore, `%mdat` acts as a sort of per-individual-embperl-page but user-independent data store.

To answer your "when" question, an example of using `%mdat` in practice would be per-page visit counter.

Comment: BTW, I must admit that in several years of Embperl based web development I *never* had any reason to use `%mdat`